# Can't retrieve column in AfterProperties when it is hidden

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers, afterproperties

How do I retrieve a column that is hidden (List content type >> Change content type column >> hidden) in the **AfterProperties** when using event receivers?

```
properties.AfterProperties["columnName"] = "new value"; //returning null because columnName is hidden
```

I noticed that when the events are triggered from document library, the hidden column can still be retrieved and updated but it returned null when triggered from custom list.

Comment: For which event you are accessing column?? for example, ItemAdding, ItemAdded, etc...

Comment: ItemUpdating and ItemAdding.

Comment: AfterProperties have values only if you really change the value for that fields. If you don't, you'll obtain a collection of 0 items. As per your question description "ColumnName" is hidden and you will never update it's value from New or Edit form. Therefore it will be always null.

Comment: Thanks, then I guess I need to find another way to update the value.

Comment: But strangely, it seems that I can retrieve and update hidden columns' values if they are from document library.